# SEO for bilinguals: What's the best way to handle translated/transliterated terms?

Tags: seo, multilingual, translation

I run a website for English-speaking expats, who search for terms in English, the local language, and translations of the local language into English (which have their own variations depending on their parent country).

What's the best way to link all these terms together and let search engines know they're all referring to the same thing?

E.g. Ministry of Transportation = Misrad Hatachbura = משרד התחבורה

Comment: This answer may be relevent: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/116564/use-english-for-h1-tag-and-title-tag-for-non-english-blog/116654#116654

Comment: Thanks, but unless I misunderstood, that post addresses a different use case: ranking pages for one language, when the page itself if written in a different one.
Im trying to use term synonyms of varying languages/transliteration in my writing without it looking spammy to either the reader or the search engines.

E.g: "Once you have completed the form, bring it to the local Ministry of Transportation (Misrad Hatachbura | משרד התחבורה) branch". Except, its dozens of the same _and_ different term, on countless pages.

Comment: Obviously this doesnt exist, but I was hopeing for something along the lines of `<span alt_lang="משרד התחבורה | he-IL" alt_lang="Misrad Hatachbura | en-IL">Ministry of Transportation</span>`

I feel like `<p>Ministry of Transportation <span display="none">Misrad Hatachbura</span><span display="none">משרד התחבורה</span></p>` is a horrible way to go.